# In Gmail, select threads which did not have any activity for a given time

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

Let's say John sent me an email 10 years ago, we kept answering on the same thread once a year and the last email was sent today. The the thread has emails from 2005,2006,... 2015.

If I type `older_than:3y` and send all the results to the trash, it seems *all* the thread is sent to the trash, including the email I sent today.

Is it possible to select only the threads which did not have any activity in the last year (for example)? The goal is to avoid deleting a very old email which I forwarded a few days ago (meaning it is not obsolete).